# How to Restore Sticky Notes?

Tags: windows-7, sticky-notes

How can I restore a sticky note in Windows 7. It is important. I was typing on it and the yellow square suddenly just went blank. I scrolled up and down but the entire thing was blank. The note remained but it was blank. How could this happen? And can I restore it?

It is a song someone wrote for me.It is very important, because I am producing a album. I have tried to follow instructions posted by someone already, but no info opens up. I posted:   `%AppData%\Microsoft\Sticky Notes\StickyNotes.snt`  as someone suggested, but it did not work. It said there is no program to open it.

Comment: Can't you right click on it and open it with WordPad ?

Comment: You didn't try undoing the action using Ctrl+Z?

Comment: David and all,  How do I open it in wordpad?  If I right click on the little square it just gives me options to change the color, delete, cut, paste; no mention of wordpad, or office,, or any such.  Is there a way to choose to open it in wordpad?    And re ctrl+z see answer below.

Comment: Thanks Torpedo;  how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it and see if it brings anything back.

Comment: David, thanks for answering.  I tried your suggestion, and it did momentarily fly past on the yellow square, as tho it was scrolling, very fast, and it vanished in an instant.  Retries have not had any effect at all, but that seems to indicate that it is still in there, on that page, somewhere.  Know any other tricks like that?